# Mercurial shows untracked files after a clone

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I've pulled changes from our central repository and notice from the command line that I have untracked files, trying to add them does nothing, any operation on them acted if it is tracked but hg status always shows they are untracked. TortioseHg shows they are not untracked, it is only happening on the command line.

I started again with a clean clone, and still files shows untracked when doing hg status?

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: What kinds of files are these?

Comment: about 10 png files and 15 css files

Comment: Can you post the output of `hg status`?

Comment: Maybe you have some kind of case folding issue? Are you working in mixed Windows/Unix environment?

Comment: @MichalSznajder that is exactly my problem, but I'm not working in mixed environment, but a folder name got renamed with a different case, I did a manual move to the new folder name and everything is correct now.